# How to Deploy ASP.NET Core MVC with Vs Code on a Mac?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, ftp, publish

I'm developing a ASP.NET Core app with VS Code on a Mac, and it is time to publish.

I ordered a server (Not azure), registered the domain, but I'm not quite sure about how to deploy this to my Host.

The Host sended to me a Publish Profile, can I deploy my application with VS Code on a Mac ?

Or should I publish in a local folder then send to the host via FTP?

Thanks in advance.

I came thought the Windows Side of the force, and with the publish profile in Visual Studio for Windows, it just works...Now, on a Mac is really confusing.

I`m not using Visual Studio for Mac because its too slow (Macbook air).

Comment: I know this is not answering your question, but why not setup a pipeline in Azure DevOps.  Releasing local, instead of from a repository is a bit dangerous.  Again, not answering the question, just giving a different avenue.

Comment: I like the idea, i already deploy a PHP project in the Azure DevOps, maybe later i will try that. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found my solution.

After developing the site. I should run a

```
dotnet publish
```

and then, get the publish folder that was created in the process and upload to my host via FTP (inside the wwwroot folder).

That's it.